# Query does not work when i fetch data and insert it into a table

Tags: php, sql, database

I am trying to insert to another table the results of a select statement from another table. The select statement works but the insert statement does not work. Please help me.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM subject WHERE sub_code = '$enrol' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $csubject=$row['sub_name'];
  $cday=$row['sub_day'];
  $ctime=$row['sub_time'];

  echo "<strong>". $csubject . "</strong>";
}

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO client (client_csub_code,client_csub_name,client_csub_day,client_csub_time) VALUES ('$enrol','$csubject','$cday','$ctime')");

header("Location:homeclient.php");
?>
```

Comment: Define "does not work". What does not work? Where?

Comment: you can combine those queries

Comment: the insert statement does not work. how can i combine it?

Comment: is your first query returns one row ?

Comment: What does "Does not work" mean? For instance, telling a mechanic your car "does not work" does not actually say anything. Does it give an error? Is it not appearing in the database? What is not working.

Comment: Change your `mysql_query(...)` to `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` and take a look at the error.

Comment: You should use mysqli or PDO with prepared statements, mysql_ functions have been deprecated. You should at least use mysql_real_escape_string() to help protect against sql injection. As marcel said, use or die and show what error you get

Answer (score 0):

You asked for how to do these two as one query.

This is how:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `client` ( `client_csub_code`, `client_csub_name`, `client_csub_day`, `client_csub_time` ) SELECT `sub_code`, `sub_name`, `sub_day`, `sub_time` FROM `subject` WHERE `code` = '$enrol'");

// I would also add error checking
if ( mysql_errno() )
    echo mysql_error();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM subject WHERE sub_code = '$enrol' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $csubject=$row['sub_name'];
  $cday=$row['sub_day'];
  $ctime=$row['sub_time'];

  echo "<strong>". $csubject . "</strong>";
  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO client (client_csub_code,client_csub_name,client_csub_day,client_csub_time) VALUES ('$enrol','$csubject','$cday','$ctime')");
}   
header("Location:homeclient.php");
?>
```

Try changing to this. Currently your query is outside of your while, it will only run once and the values of $csubject etc are always going to be the last values of your fetched results.

Comment: You want to put an insert query into a loop...really ?